# Reducing higly correlating variables with selection criterion

Tags: r, correlation

I have a large inconsistent dataset that has a bunch of highly correlating variables. What I want to is reduce the amount of correlating variables that correlate above a threshold of 0.7. However, I want the selected/remaining variable to be the one that had the strongest correlation with a pre-defined variable. For example, *x* as that selected variable the following correlation matrix:

```
     x      y      z      m 
 x 1      0.1    0.2    0.3
 y 0.1    1      0.9    0.11   
 z 0.2    0.9    1      0.6
 m 0.3    0.11   0.60   1
```

Should be reduced to:

```
     x      z     m 
 x 1      0.2   0.3
 z 0.2      1   0.6
 m 0.3   0.60     1
```

Because *z* and *y* surpass the 0.7 threshold and *z* correlates stronger with *x* than *y*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cludgy, but it seems to work.

```
# Define matrix
mat <- matrix(c(1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,1,0.9,0.11,0.2,0.9,1,0.6,0.3,0.11,0.60,1), ncol = 4)

# Add names
row.names(mat) <- colnames(mat) <- c("x", "y", "z", "m")

# Specify threshold
threshold <- 0.7

# Selected variable
i <- "x"

# Get column number of selected variable
i <- which(colnames(mat) == i)

# Find element above threshold
above.threshold <- matrix(which(abs(mat) > threshold & mat != 1, arr.ind = TRUE), ncol = 2)

# Remove duplicates
above.threshold <- above.threshold[above.threshold[,1]>above.threshold[,2],,drop = FALSE] 

# Variables to remove
var.rm <- apply(above.threshold, MAR = 1, function(foo)names(which.min(mat[i,foo])))

# New matrix
mat <- mat[!(rownames(mat) %in% var.rm), !(colnames(mat) %in% var.rm)]
```

That produces,

```
    x   z   m
x 1.0 0.2 0.3
z 0.2 1.0 0.6
m 0.3 0.6 1.0
```

If threshold is set to 0.5 it produces,

```
    x   m
x 1.0 0.3
m 0.3 1.0
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much, this is exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If your selected col is x, find values lower than a certain point:

```
low = which(df[,1]<0.0.4)
```

and select the remaing rows/cols using

```
test[-low,-low]
```